# Using Django sessions

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-sessions

i have got some problem on implementing Django sessions. I have an employee listing page with a filter option on it. Filtering is done based on the fields and a text entered in a text box. The users filtered is displayed in the filter.html page; clicking on the user name takes to that user's profile page. Now i want to go back to the previous page (given a back button in the employee profile page) where the filtered users were displayed(filter.html). I guess this could be done by sessions. But i am not sure the way i use sessions is correct. Please help me to solve this as i am new to Django. Will post my code here:

```
def filter(request):
    val=request.POST.get('designation')      
    val2=request.POST.get('choices')
    val3=request.POST.get('textField')

    if val2=='Designation':                
        newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(designation=request.POST.get('textField'))  
        request.session['session_textField']="textField"  
        request.session['session_choices']="choices"    
        session_textField = request.session["session_textField"]
        session_choices = request.session["session_choices"]
        print session_textField,session_choices
    elif val2=='Name':
        newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(userName=request.POST.get('textField'))
        request.session['session_textField']="textField"  
        request.session['session_choices']="choices"      
        session_textField = request.session["session_textField"]
        session_choices = request.session["session_choices"]
        print session_textField,session_choices        
    elif val2=='EmployeeID':
        newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(employeeID=request.POST.get('textField'))        
        request.session['session_textField']="textField"  
        request.session['session_choices']="choices"      
        session_textField = request.session["session_textField"]
        session_choices = request.session["session_choices"]
        print session_textField,session_choices  
    elif val2=='Project':
        newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(project=request.POST.get('textField'))     
        request.session['session_textField']="textField"  
        request.session['session_choices']="choices"      
        session_textField = request.session["session_textField"]
        session_choices = request.session["session_choices"]
        print session_textField,session_choices     
    elif val2=='DateOfJoin':
        newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(dateOfJoin=request.POST.get('textField'))       
        request.session['session_textField']="textField"  
        request.session['session_choices']="choices"      
        session_textField = request.session["session_textField"]
        session_choices = request.session["session_choices"]
        print session_textField,session_choices   
    else:
        return render_to_response('filter.html') 

    return render_to_response('filter.html',{'newData':newData,'val2':val2})
```

Filter.html

```
<html>
<h3><br><br>
The Filtered Data 
</h3>
<body>
<br>
{%for data in newData%}
<a href ="http://10.1.0.90:8080/singleEmployee/{{data.id}} ">
{{ data.userName}}<br>
{%endfor%} 
</body><br><br><br><br>
<a href ="http://10.1.0.90:8080/employeeList/ "> Home Page  </a>
</html>
```

Employee Profile html page

```
<table>
<tr> <td>Name: {{ empSelect.userName }} </td> </tr><td>
<tr> <td>Designation: {{ empSelect.designation }} </td> </tr><td>
<tr> <td>Employee ID: {{ empSelect.employeeID }} </td> </tr><td>
<tr> <td>Contact Number: {{ empSelect.contactNumber }} </td> </tr><td>
<tr> <td>Project: {{ empSelect.project }} </td> </tr><td>
<tr> <td>Date Of Join: {{ empSelect.dateOfJoin }} </td> </tr><td>
</table></h4><br>
<input type="submit" value="Delete User" onClick="window.location.href='/userDelete/{{empSelect.id}}'"/>
<input type="submit" value="Update User" onClick="window.location.href='/userUpdate/{{empSelect.id}}'"/>
</div><br><br>
<a href ="http://10.1.0.90:8080/filter/{{emp.id}} "> Back  </a><br><br>
<a href ="http://10.1.0.90:8080/employeeList/ "> Home Page  </a>
</body></html>
```

If the code i provided has a lot of error, please help me to correct it.

Comment: So... what's the error again?

Comment: i am not able to get the session values when i click the 'back' button from the employee profile page..

Comment: Hitting the back button doesn't reload the page.

Comment: Have a link pointing to 'filter' function :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not at all clear what you are trying to do. But notice this:

```
request.session['session_textField']="textField"  
request.session['session_choices']="choices"
```

These two lines, which are identical in every block, simply set the two session variables to the strings "textField" and "choices". I don't think this is what you want to do, although as I say above I don't know exactly what you *do* want to do. However, this seems to be an elementary programming problem, not anything to do with Django sessions in particular.